# Кроссбраузерность сайта

Tags: html, safari, img

Столкнулся с проблемой кроссбраузерности сайта, в браузере safari не отображаются изображения. Проверили с нескольких маков, проблема подтвердилась.

Сталкивался раньше с проблемой применения стилей, но с отображением картинок первый раз, в чем может быть проблема?

Добавлю два скриншота для большей ясности ситуации.

[image: Chrome Windows]
[image: Safari Mac]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема с форматом изображений. Скорее свего они в формате `.webp`, который пока [не поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=webp) всеми брузерами.
Дайте ссылку на ресурс для диагностики.

Comment: https://makovska.com

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас проблема с интернет-соединением, проверил - все грузится. Попробуйте очистить кеш-браузера и обновить страницу <kbd>CMD + R</kbd>.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как писал раньше, пробовал тестировать на разных маках и проблема повторялась. А какая у вас версия safari?

Comment: признаюсь у меня винда пользовался https://crossbrowsertesting.com/ - скорее всего проблема не с сафари